# How to show select form by seleting it from dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I want to show Different form page on selecting value from drop-down-list. i have a two web pages first i have drop-down list and on second page i have a form now i want when i select value from my drop-down list for for that value will appear how can i do this can any one help me.

first form aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div style="margin-left: 80px">
       <asp:Label ID="lblPortal" runat="server" Text="Select Portal"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPortal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
       onselectedindexchanged="MyPage">
       <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>TRAVELONG</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>ONETRAVEL</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>.UK</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>.CA-YYZ</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>.CA-YVR</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
```

Second aspx form:

```
<div style="margin-left: 80px">
   <asp:Label ID="lblPortal" runat="server" Text="Select Portal"></asp:Label>

   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPortal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
       onselectedindexchanged="MyPage_Indexchange">
       <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>TRAVELONG</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>ONETRAVEL</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>.UK</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>.CA-YYZ</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>.CA-YVR</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vdm" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
<table class="style1">
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblTid" runat="server" Text="TID"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbTid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTid" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbTid" ErrorMessage="Enter Tid" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblUnusedTicketAmount" runat="server" 
                   Text="Unused Ticket Amount"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbUnusedTicketAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUnusedTicketAmount" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbUnusedTicketAmount" ErrorMessage="Enter Amount" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnusedAmount" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style14">
               <asp:Label ID="lblPNR" runat="server" Text="PNR"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style9">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbPNR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style8">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPNR" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbPNR" ErrorMessage="Enter PNR" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style9">
               <asp:Label ID="lblAirlinePenality" runat="server" Text="Airline Penality"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style12">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbAirlinePenality" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style10">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAirlinePenality" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbAirlinePenality" ErrorMessage="Enter Penality" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style10">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAirlinePenality" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblTicketNumber" runat="server" Text="Ticket Number"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbTicketNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTicketNumber" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbTicketNumber" ErrorMessage="Enter ESAC" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblNetRefundProcess" runat="server" Text="Net Refund Process"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbNetRefundProcess" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNetRefundProcess" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbNetRefundProcess" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNetRefundProcess" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblESACCode" runat="server" Text="ESAC Code"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbESACCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvESACCode" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbESACCode" ErrorMessage="Enter ESAC code" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblRefundableCommision" runat="server" 
                   Text="Refundable Commission"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbRefundableCommision" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRefundableCommission" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbRefundableCommision" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRefundableCommission" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>USD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>GBP</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="lblWaiverCode" runat="server" Text="Waiver Code"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbWaiverCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvWaiverCode" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbWaiverCode" ErrorMessage="Enter Waiver Code" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblCouponRefunded" runat="server" Text="Coupon Refunded"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbCouponRefund" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCouponRefunded" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbCouponRefund" ErrorMessage="Enter Coupon Refund" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13">
               <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Remarks"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbRemarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td class="style4">
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRemarks" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="tbRemarks" ErrorMessage="Enter Remarks" Font-Bold="True" 
                   ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td class="style5">
               <asp:Label ID="lblRefundType" runat="server" Text="Refund Type"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td class="style11">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRefundType" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem>Full</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>Partial</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRefundType" runat="server" 
                   ControlToValidate="ddlRefundType" ErrorMessage="Select Refund Type" 
                   Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="style13" colspan="7">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
               &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                   Text="Submit" />
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table> 
   </div>
```

Second Form .cs file code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void MyPage_Indexchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(@"~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by using well-known technique called [Cross-Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In a few words: you perform a post back to another page, where you can access the controls from the original page.

Unfortunately, `DropDownList` doesn't have this feature built-in (like a `Button` control with a [`PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property), but [`PostBackOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbackoptions.aspx) to the rescue.

Form1 (assuming, this is `~\default.aspx`):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pbo = new PostBackOptions(ddlPortal);
    pbo.ActionUrl = "default2.aspx";
    pbo.AutoPostBack = true;
    ddlPortal.Attributes["onchange"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(pbo);
}
```

and then add:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/default.aspx" %>
```

to the second form (assuming, this is `default2.aspx`), and add the next to the second page's `Page_Load` event handler:

```
if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
{
    var ddlPortal = (DropDownList)PreviousPage.FindControl("ddlPortal");
    var selectedValue = ddlPortal.SelectedValue;
    // do something with the value from the previous page
}
```

It is quite easy, isn't it?

Comment: i have to add directive on my default page or default2 page

Comment: @amitesh: I'm assuming, you're on `default.aspx` page, and then make a postback to `default2.aspx`. In that case, `PreviousPageType` should be added to the second page to define the first page type.